# System.out.println not printing array data

Tags: java, arrays, system.out

I am still very new to Java and have been trying to get a morse code translator to work. I overcame the first problem with various errors, but now the program compiles but will not print the results of the translation. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MorseCode
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("To convert English to Morse Code, type M. To convert Morse Code to English, type E.");

        String cType = Input.nextLine();

        String type = cType.toLowerCase();

        if(type == "m")
        {
            String eng;
            System.out.println("Please enter the English text to be translated.");
            eng = Input.nextLine();
            EToM(eng);
        }
        else
        {
            String morse;
            System.out.println("Please enter the Morse code text to be translated, with multiple words seperated by a |.");
            morse = Input.nextLine();
            MToE(morse);
        }
    }
    public static void EToM(String eng)
    {
        String EToMList[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".--", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "----.", "-----", "|"};

        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789 ";
        String translation[] = new String[eng.length()];

        for(int x = 0; x < eng.length(); x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < alphabet.length(); y++)
            {
                if(eng.charAt(x) == alphabet.charAt(y))
                {
                    translation[x] = EToMList[y];
                    System.out.println("test");
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Your translated message is:");

        for(int z = 0; z < eng.length(); z++)
        {
            System.out.println(translation[z]); 
        }
    }

    public static void MToE(String morse)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: try printing out something after you print out the contents of your array, and see how many iterations of your loop are running

Comment: and use equals() instead of == for String/Object comparison

Comment: Although your method is grossly inefficient in terms of coding, it compiles and runs fine ([demo link](http://ideone.com/UGDpGB)).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is

```
if(type == "m")
```

use

```
if("m".equals(type))
```

Your `if-else` will go to `else` because you are comparing String references and not String values. The `else` calls the `MToE` method which is empty. Read this: [How Do I compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: It looks to me like everything that the OP expects to happen before the printing of the translation is happening.  If `type=="m"` was the issue, than it would never even print the `"test"` lines that the OP has

Comment: @SamIam I haven't seen OP state that `test` was printed.

Comment: Why would the OP tell you that the problem was with the `results` if there's evidence of failure before `results`?

Comment: @SamIam Because OP is _still very new to Java_. OP mus think there are results, but there actually aren't.

Comment: That's why i didn't actually down-vote; it's foolish to assume that the OP didn't miss any obvious symptoms, but I'm not up-voting either, at least not until the OP verifies that it is the issue.

Comment: @SamIam OP has provided an SSCE, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

When checking strings for equality in Java, always use the [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method on the String class. Changing the following:

```
if(type == "m")
```

to

```
if(type.equals("m"))
```

makes the English to Morse code translation output.

I made this modification and ran it successfully just now.

Answer (score 0):

use This

```
  if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("m")
  {

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the deepToString method from Java to print out your array.

Documentation Link:
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Here is a code sample:

```
System.out.println("Your translated message is:" + java.util.Arrays.deepToString(translation));
```